# Display only one category

Tags: magento-1.9, category, navigation, third-party-module

Here is the code which displays all the categories and sub categories.

I would like to display only categories and subcategories of root category with id 7.

```
<?php $store_categories = $this->toLinearArray($this->getStoreCategories()) ?>
<?php if ($count = count($store_categories)): ?>
        <ul id="vertnav">
<?php endif; ?>
<?php foreach ($store_categories as $i => $_category): ?><?php $class = array() ?>
<?php if ($count == 1): ?>
<?php $class[] = 'only' ?>
<?php elseif (! $i): ?>
<?php $class[] = 'first' ?>
<?php elseif ($i == $count-1): ?>
<?php $class[] = 'last' ?>
<?php endif; ?>
<?php if (isset($store_categories[$i+1]) && $this->isCategoryActive($store_categories[$i+1])) $class[] = 'prev'; ?>
<?php if (isset($store_categories[$i-1]) && $this->isCategoryActive($store_categories[$i-1])) $class[] = 'next'; ?>
<?php echo $this->drawOpenCategoryItem($_category, 0, $class) ?>
<?php endforeach ?>
<?php if ($count): ?>
        </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: Is this from https://github.com/riconeitzel/VertNav?

Comment: I think so, I really don't know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code looks like it's from https://github.com/riconeitzel/VertNav, so please try to add this to:

> app/design/frontend/THEME/PACKAGE/layout/local.xml:

```
<reference name="catalog.vertnav">
    <action method="setCategoryId"><category_id>7</category_id></action>
</reference>
```